# Rails: Count unique records, disregarding a certain column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following table

```
| Name   | Food  | Price |
--------------------------
| Alice  | Pizza | 5     |
| Alice  | Pizza | 10    |
| Alice  | Salad | 5     |
| Bob    | Soup  | 20    |
| Bob    | Soup  | 15    |
| Carol  | Pork  | 10    |
--------------------------
```

I would like to find something like

```
------------------------
| Name   | UniqueFoods |
------------------------
| Alice  | 2           | # Pizza and Salad
| Bob    | 1           | # Has only had soup, despite having it twice
| Carol  | 1           |
------------------------
```

I have tried various things like

```
Person.select(:name, "count(*) AS uniquefoods").distinct.group(:name)
```

However, this produces

```
------------------------
| Name   | UniqueFoods |
------------------------
| Alice  | 3           | # incorrect
| Bob    | 2           | # incorrect
| Carol  | 1           |
------------------------
```

I would like to replace `.distinct` with something that only considers the `name` and `food` columns, and disregards price, so it would remove duplicate Name/Food pairs before groping.

Alternately, if there's an easier way to produce this `UniqueFoods` column, that would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `distinct` in wrong place (which is useless in your case because you have `group` after it).

```
Person.select(:name, "count(distinct food) AS uniquefoods").group(:name)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your original solution is that it evaluates to `SELECT DISTINCT people.name, count(*) AS uniquefoods FROM people GROUP BY people.name`, which is counting the total number of foods per unique person. I would avoid the accepted solution using select because it unnecessarily loads your Person records and it's syntax you would never write to solve this problem as a Rails developer. Here are examples of queries more consistent with best practices:

Grouping by name and performing a count calculation on distinct foods will return a hash of names to distinct food counts:

```rb
# Here are 2 examples
Person.group(:name).distinct(:food).count(:food)
Person.group(:name).count('distinct food')
=> { "Alice" => 2, "Bob" => 1, "Carol" => 1 }
```

That is the go-to solution for performing count calculations, and the results are nicely accessible in constant time because it returns them as a hash. You can pass `group` one or more values to use for the key, and the value will be whatever you `count`ed. When performing a group on multiple columns, the hash key is an array containing the two grouped values.

Alternatively, you can use `pluck` to return an array of the values you want from one or more columns:

```rb
# Plucking 2+ columns yields a 2-dimensional array simulating rows
Person.group(:name).pluck(:name, 'count(distinct food)')
=> [["Alice", 2], ["Bob", 1], ["Carol", 1]]

# Plucking 1 column yields a 1-dimensional array simulating a column
Person.distinct(:name).pluck(:name)
=> ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"]
```

Pluck is super handy and has performance benefits over `select`, though most commonly you'll see it used to select the values from a single column.

Rails query methods are generally really flexible. If you aren't familiar with it, check out the Rails guide on AR querying: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html